# Java incompatible types string can't be converted to double

Tags: java

I'm new to `Java` and I'm doing an autonomous mode for my robotics team and I keep getting this error:

`ERROR: incompatible types:java.lang.String cannot be converted to double`

what would cause this?

Comment: Show some code that is throwing that. It seems that you are trying to convert a String to a Double and the string is not a valid double. What is the value in the string when you try to convert it?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you try to set a double value from a string value like this:

```
double x = "5.3";
```

What you should do is like the following:

```
double x = Double.parseDouble("5.3");
```

Happy coding;